# Error trying to access AWS S3 using Pyspark

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to access gzip files from AWS S3 using Spark. I have a very simple script below. I first started off 
with a IAM user with access permissions to the S3 bucket. Then I created an EC2 instance & installed Python & Spark.
I setup the spark.properties file as below. I only copied the jar files, didn't bother to go through the entire Hadoop installation. 
Then I realized I have to create an IAM role for EC2 instances to access S3. 
So, I created an IAM role, attached an access policy and then attached the role to EC2. Did not restart EC2 instance. 
What am I doing wrong? My goal is to get comfortable with Pyspark on a standalone environment before I proceed to EMR, clusters, etc.

I execute Pyspark as:
`enter code here`spark-submit --properties-file spark.properties S3Access.py

My Pyspark code:

```
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from boto3.session import Session

ACCESS_KEY = 'blah blah'
SECRET_KEY = 'blah blah'
BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket'
PREFIX = 'folder-name/'
MAX_FILES_READ = 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
        # Use Boto to connect to S3 and get a list of objects from a bucket
        session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

        s3 = session.resource('s3')

        # call S3 to list current buckets
        my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

        # Get a Spark context and use it to parallelize the keys
        conf = SparkConf().setAppName("MyFirstProcessingApp")
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

        index = 0
        for s3_file in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=PREFIX):
                if 'gz' in s3_file.key:
                        index += 1
                        print ("Found file: ", s3_file.key)
                        if index == MAX_FILES_READ:
                                break
                        fileLocation = "s3a://" + BUCKET_NAME + '/path-to-file/path/filename.txt'
                        print ("file location: ", fileLocation)
                        s3File = sc.textFile(fileLocation)
                        count = s3File.count()
```

Error I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-57-35:/opt/iqmedia$ spark-submit --properties-file spark.properties S3Access.py
19/07/22 01:15:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found file:  inscape/content/2019-01-01/2019-01-01-07.0000_part_00.gz
file location:  s3a://bucket/folder/filename.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/iqmedia/S3Access.py", line 42, in <module>
    count = s3File.count()
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1055, in count
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1046, in sum
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 917, in fold
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 816, in collect
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 35CB499B1AE1A8A6, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: BHnH2DO+HuvARy9d3hdfCrtc2ToSJ7DQ/6ODSymLfDOZF7G80rpJqyyvkVuXdAPsR2a9gjqxWX8=
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:976)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:956)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:892)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1676)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Updated July 22**:
I did everything like mentioned except running Notebook. I ran the script again and got the following error. Any thoughts?

```
File "/opt/iqmedia/S3Access.py", line 39, in <module>
    print(s3File.count())
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1055, in count
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1046, in sum
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 917, in fold
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 816, in collect
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
```

**Updated July 22 evening:**
Well, I got past everything. I think I was using the wrong Hadoop jar file. My bashrc looks like this now even though I don't have Notebook working.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
```

Now, I am able to run a simple Spark command to measure the size of a file. But I am still getting the error below.

```
NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: ignore the warning about native code; even turn that log off. It means there's no hadoop native lib. Everything will work (on unix; windows is different), though without the native codes compression and decompression will be slower

Comment: oh wow. I just went through this entire process this last week, just finished it yesterday. I did it for docker though. I'll say right out of the gate you're 99% certainly going to be wanting to run python 3.6 or higher if you are coding new code. Either way, I did the same thing mostly on my mac (except i used brew of course).  the code in this gist works fine, seems to have full access to all my s3 via pyspark. https://gist.github.com/tonyfraser/9a16ba9739d91f26e52fa4e89a492669.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you go via this route that I'm mentioning below, because I've faced issues with s3 and pyspark in the past, and whatever I did wasn't good for my head, or for the wall.

1. Download spark on your local (version 2.4.x prebuilt for hadoop 2.7)
2. Set your env variables (e.g. SPARK_HOME), and add it to PATH.

   - On MacOS I add it to `~/.bash_profile`. Should be similar for other OSs.
3. Download [hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.3/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar) and [aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar) and save these inside some folder (e.g. `/users/me/test-spark`). One thing to remember here is that if you use any other version, you'll be in agony.
4. Add these two lines in your `spark-defaults.conf` file which you can find inside the spark installation path:

> spark.driver.extraClassPath    :/users/me/test-spark/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar:/users/me/test-spark/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
>
> spark.executor.extraClassPath   :/users/me/test-spark/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar:/users/me/test-spark/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar

5. Download Anaconda, jupyter comes bundled with it, so no headache. Configure your jupyter to bind to a particular python, spark on your local.

   - On MacOS I add these variables with proper values in `~/.bash_profile` (`PYTHONPATH`, `PYSPARK_PYTHON`, `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`, `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS`). You can find tutorials online that show how to set these values.

---

Once you've done all these prerequisites you can move to next stage:

6. Paste the following code-snippet in your notebook and run. I think your code had some issues where the file names are hard-coded. So they are pointing to some non-existent objects in S3.

```py
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from boto3.session import Session

ACCESS_KEY = 'blah blah blah?'
SECRET_KEY = 'blah blah blah!'
BUCKET_NAME = 'my-leaky-bucket'
PREFIX = 'root'
MAX_FILES_READ = 3

# Use Boto to connect to S3 and get a list of objects from a bucket
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

s3 = session.resource('s3')

# call S3 to list current buckets
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MyFirstProcessingApp').master('local[2]').getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", ACCESS_KEY)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_KEY)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")

index = 0
for s3_file in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=PREFIX):
    if 'gz' in s3_file.key:
        index += 1
        print ("Found file: {file}".format(file=s3_file.key))
        if index == MAX_FILES_READ:
            break
        fileLocation = "s3a://{bucket}/{file}".format(bucket=BUCKET_NAME,file=s3_file.key)
        print ("file location: {loc}".format(loc=fileLocation))
        s3File = sc.textFile(fileLocation)
        print(s3File.count())
        print('\n')
```

**Additional Note**: This is kinda amazing that if you create an EMR Cluster and attach a jupyter notebook to it (from AWS Web-UI), it takes care of everything. You can simply copy-paste the code snippet in that Jupyter notebook, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks Bitswazsky. This was very helpful. My EC2 instance doesn't have UI so I guess can't use Notebook. Now, when I do "spark-submit S3Access.py", I get an error saying "UNable to load native hadoop library for your platform...using builtin-java classes...". Error executing Jupyter command '/opt/iqmedia/S3Access.py'. No such file or directory.

Comment: You can have notebook on EC2 and use the UI on your local as well. Just open an ssh tunnel on port 8888 (or whatever port you use for Jupyter). Use this guide for tunneling: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel-local.html The first one is fine, that's a warning message. I think you're giving incorrect path in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the HADOOP_HOME as later tried by @NetRocks helped to solve my case.
If you are using the Spark (Hadoop bundled version) then make sure you set the SPARK_HOME and HADOOP_HOME to the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Following the @Bitswazsky's answer & using below

```
import os
import os.path
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pathlib import Path
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from boto3.session import Session


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="ASI...XHMRZ"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="1FCz...M4pWXUcP"
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="IQoJb3JpZ2l.....ZOBs7pIzzy7QXc0UAhyAYLtUvzHcB1CO98Jwk3PtGNkS4baykkUssDxOkvp01U/8F7pu6Vog=="
BUCKET_NAME = 'my-sandbox'
profile_name='3716-Developer'

PREFIX = 'root'
MAX_FILES_READ = 3

# Use Boto to connect to S3 and get a list of objects from a bucket
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
# call S3 to list current buckets
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MyFirstProcessingApp').master('local[2]').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("s3a://my-sandbox/tmp/cust_df_f_zip.parquet"
```

On Windows WSL
$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-3DKM78D 4.19.128-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 12:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
____              __
/ **/**  ___ *****/ /**
*\ / _ / _ `/ __/  '*/
/** / .__/_,*/*/ /*/_\   version 2.4.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spark_s3_access.py", line 31, in <module>
    df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("s3a://my-sandbox/tmp/cust_df_f_zip.parquet")
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 166, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.load.
: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 9B95DBA6D53DA18A, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: //lgkjl8/vZMxVqfX7jc1wfFEaXbUH+XuAjolL4SnCzATl1UzylUcoWe8cH4LggvDMza4cXdATs=
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
```

on the last line reading parquet: df = spark.read...

```
(cor_poc) syoon@DESKTOP-$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/opt/spark
(cor_poc) syoon@DESKTOP$ echo $SPARK_HOME
/opt/spark
(cor_poc) syoon@DESKTOP$ echo $PATH
/home/syoon/.nvm/versions/node/v14.14.0/bin:...:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/db/bin:/opt/spark/bin

(cor_poc) syoon@DESKTOP-3DKM78D:~/Prj/processing_rqsts/paul_df1_01$ tail /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
# Example:
# spark.master                     spark://master:7077
# spark.eventLog.enabled           true
# spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
# spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
# spark.driver.memory              5g
# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"

spark.driver.extraClassPath :/opt/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar:/opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath :/opt/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar:/opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
```

but I do have the permission:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://my-sandbox/tmp/
2020-11-02 13:51:36          0
2020-11-02 20:52:46   18283514 cust_df.parquet
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[NetRocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5203233/netrocks) You did not say what your platform was, but here is a [guide](https://gist.github.com/borislitvak/4c4fc72ed65f58042b84e2f36e3d720e) on pyspark installation on Windows and AWS S3 access configuration.

Judging by the error you are getting, you are missing `hadoop-aws.jar`.